# htaccess - rewriting rules

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, rule

Google Webmaster tools gives me a hint that I have 2 pages with the exact same content.

For example:

```
/airports/romania/115.php
/airports/romania/115.phphey1
```

In the htacces file i have this:

```
RewriteRule airports/(.*)/([0-9]{1,}).php airports_list.php?airport=$2&country_air=$1
```

I've checked and double checked and triple checked all my code in airports_list.php and every other file on the server. I can't find "hey1" anywhere.

In order to solve my problem, I think I have to redirect a link like www.mydomain.com/airports/romania/115.phphey1 to a 404 page.

How do I do that ?

The following is also working inside my .htaccess file :

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mydomain.com/404.php
```

Comment: Put a dollar sign at the end of that regex.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that the dollar sign stops pattern matching at that point, even if there are more characters beyond "php" !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a dollar sign at the end of the regex, it stops matching and so garbage at the end of '.php' and goes to the 404.

```
RewriteRule airports/(.*)/([0-9]{1,}).php$ airports_list.php?airport=$2&country_air=$1
```

Comment: Google Webmaster tools gave me the same hint (double content) for 2 other pages: `tickets-to-cityname.html` and `tickets-to-cityname.html?city=cityname` . tickets-to-cityname.html is created with another rewrite rule: `RewriteRule tickets-to-(.*).html$ tickets/view-tickets.php?city=$1`
How can I solve this? :(